# why is limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}⌊\frac{\sin x}{x}⌋ = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was evaluating the limit
$$f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor$$
and I substituted the [equivalent infinitesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Equivalent_infinitesimal) $\sin(x) \sim x$, obtaining $f(x) = 1$. But on observing the graph of $⌊\frac{\sin x}{x}⌋$, the limit comes out be $0$. However, evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} ⌊\frac{\tan x}{x}⌋$ the same way, algebraic result matches with the graphical one. So what is going wrong in the first limit?

Comment: We have $\lvert \sin x \rvert < \lvert x\rvert$ for $x \neq 0$, but $\lvert x\rvert < \lvert \tan x \rvert$.

Comment: what graph of sinx/x are you using ?

Comment: Evaluating $\ldots$ the "sane" way or the "same" way? Is that a typo or a great coincidence? :-)

Comment: Your argument would be valid if the function $u\mapsto\lfloor u\rfloor$ were continuous, but clearly it's not!

Comment: @AsafKaragila both apparently :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For $x>0$ we have $\sin x<x$ (this can be verified by considering the derivative of $x-\sin x$). So, for $x>0$,
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor=0
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\left\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor=0
$$
Since the function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is even, also
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\left\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor=0
$$

---

For the other limit, the situation is different: for $0<x<\pi/2$ we have $\tan x>x$ (also this can be verified by using the derivative). Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1
$$
there is $\delta>0$ such that, for $0<x<\delta$, $1<\frac{\tan x}{x}<2$ and so, for $0<x<\delta$,
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{\tan x}{x}\right\rfloor=1
$$
which gives, together with the fact that $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ is even,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left\lfloor\frac{\tan x}{x}\right\rfloor=1
$$

---

In both cases you are actually doing the limit of a constant function (in a punctured neighborhood of $0$, for the second one).

Comment: this can't possibly be true, you can see that from using l'hopital's rule or expanding sinx (tanx ) by McLauren expansion, you see that sinx/x -> 1

Comment: @david Yes, I know that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, but this has little to do with the problem at hand. The “floor” function is not continuous at $1$, so you can't “put the limit inside”.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively: Note that on $\lfloor \sin(x)/x \rfloor$, the graph approaches $1$ from below, while on $\lfloor \tan(x)/x \rfloor$, the graph approaches $1$ from above.

Therefore, while the graph of $\sin(x)/x$ *approaches* 1, it never reaches there: therefore, for small values of $x$ around 0, the value of $\lfloor \sin(x)/x \rfloor$ will be 0. However, even for small values of $x$ around 0, the value of $\lfloor \tan(x)/x \rfloor$ will be $1$, as it approaches from above and the values are greater than $1$.

Answer (score 2):

What is $$\lim_{x\to 0} \,\lfloor 1-x^2\rfloor?$$

It is not $1$. The problem is that $f(y)=\lfloor y\rfloor$ is not continuous.