# Can we say $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} $ exactly $1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

Can we say $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} $$ is exactly equal to $1$

I got this doubt while solving the limit

$$\lfloor\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\rfloor$$ because as per my knowledge $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ approaches $1$ from below hence

$$\lfloor\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\rfloor=0$$

But some books give it as $1$, so what exactly is the concept here?

Comment: $$\lfloor\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\rfloor$$ is the floor of the limit, so it's $1$ since the limit is $1$. Your reasoning seems more applicable to the limit of the floor, i.e. $$\lim_{x \to 0}\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\rfloor.$$

Comment: Then do you doubt that $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}=1$. After all, $\lim_{x\to0}\left\lfloor\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\right\rfloor=0$.

Comment: Ya so my doubt is everywhere in the world we use equal to symbol for the limits, but are they not approaching that value, so in the above example $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2+1} $ approaches one from left, so why cant we say $\lfloor{\frac{1}{x^2+1}\rfloor}$ equal to 0

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331956/why-is-limit-lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-sin-xx-0?rq=1

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis My doubt is for $\lfloor \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \rfloor$ why the answer is not zero because $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is approaching $1$ from below and Greatest integer of that  is zero.

Comment: Limit of a "thing" is something different from the "thing" itself and loosely speaking the thing approaches the limit. And again speaking loosely the limit is something fixed and it does not approach something. So you may say that $(\sin x) /x$ approaches $1$ as $x\to 1$ but the expression $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x) /x$ does not approach anything it is rather fixed and equal to $1$.

Comment: Did the answer provided solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

*I'm assuming you meant 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor=0$$in your question.* And indeed, we have both
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor=0\tag{1}$$
**and**
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1\tag{2}$$
They are *not* contradictory! What seems to trouble you is that, for $f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$, we have
$$\lim_{x \to 0}f\!\left( \frac{\sin x}{x}\right)=0 \neq 1 = 
f\!\left( \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) \tag{3}
$$
However, there is no contradiction here. Because **$f$ is not continuous at $1$** -- so there is no guarantee that "$f(\lim_n x_n)=\lim_n f(x_n)$" here.